# Embed html5 viewer in facebook timeline

Tags: facebook, iframe, embed

I would like to be abble to embed directly in the timelin our html5 viewer for tuto.
We need that our followers can use the viewer without installing any apps , directly in our timeline or in their timeline if they want to share .

This,is our standard embed viewer
http://www.peoplbrain.fr/route_embed_diapo/faire-le-chignon-tresse-epis?

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible. You must link to external or if you don't wan't redirect users outside FB - create a facebook tab application which will embed viewer. You can pass arguments to facebook tab using app_data parameter.